# Retain the value of a drop down after submitting form.

Tags: java, jsp, dropdown

Hello I want to retain the value of a drop down after submitting form.  I have a drop down where a year is selected.  After that all the contracts having that year should be displayed.

I have a drop down list in my jsp as below:

```
<html:select name="contratForm" property="annee">
    <%
        int current_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        for(int year = 2000; year<=current_year; year++)
        {
            %>
                <option> <%=year %> </option>
            <%  
            }
    %>
</html:select><SPAN class="ChampObligatoire">*</SPAN>
```

In my action, I have the following:

```
String annee = ((contratForm) form).getAnnee();
contratForm.setAnnee(annee);
request.setAttribute("contratForm", contratForm);
return mapping.findForward("success");
```

What I want is that the year selected before submitting the form, to be displayed when I return the list of contracts.
Any help please?

Comment: This is not clear, you might want to be a bit more specific but ... first, see [w2c select tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) for more information on this. You are missing the `value` tag here (might use the text there but not sure, in case of doubt, prefer to tell you ;) . Then, to select a specific value, you have mutliple solution. Adding a `selected` tag for the correct one or using javascript using the [select object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp).

Comment: Why cant you send the selected year to controller and get it back with the contracts and show it in UI?

Comment: @TheGuest : I can send the value in the Form.  However just can't figure out how to display it, since it is a dropdown list.